# I need a Validation rule that says if Task Type = Billable, then the task category must not be blank

Tags: validation-rule, validation

I need a Validation rule that says if Task Type = Billable, then the task category must not be blank.  both the task type and task category are drop-down boxes.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. This site isn't a free coding service, so you should [edit] your question to show us what you've tried so far. Even if it doesn't work or you're getting errors, sharing that information helps people give you tailored answers to help you learn. If you're new to Salesforce (or a part/feature thereof) then https://trailhead.salesforce.com is going to be a better place to start working on some base knowledge (with its more step-by-step instruction).

Answer (score 1):

Try with below code and change the `field API` names as per your org.

```
AND(ISPICKVAL(Task_Type__c,"Billable"),ISBLANK( task_category__c ))
```

Refer the [Formula Operators and Functions by Context](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions.htm&type=5)